# How to make "Promise" with a "pending" state and can be used by yield?

Tags: node.js

We can use "Promise" something like this:

```
   const pm = new Promise((resolved,rejected)=>.....);
   const result = yield pm;
```

And we cannot fetch the pending state,how to cope with that? I need something like this:

```
   const pm = new Promise((***pending***,resolved,rejected)=>....);
   const result = yield pm; //the result from pending state,resolved and rejected
```

Comment: Promise has a state called "pending".  What is a "processing state"?  You get the final state of a promise with `.then()`.

Comment: Yes, a promise has a pending state.  What is the question?  You get the final state of a promise with `.then()`.  That's the ONLY state it exposes.  I cannot tell what you're asking.

Comment: Promise only exposes us with "resolved" and "rejected", without "processing" or "pending" functions. And I cannot fetch that with yield?!

Comment: Promises do not work that way.  They just don't.  That's not how they were designed. That's not how the specification works.  If you want some different way of working, you'd have to design your own notification system.  All promises really are is a notification system.

Comment: Not that I know of.  Also, it is ***off-topic*** here to ask for a recommendation of another library.